# Where does "Don't bogart that joint" come from?

Tags: etymology, phrases, idioms

I've looked on Google for several minutes, but I can't find a plausible reason, nor any immediately useful things to follow up.

(I understand *"Don't bogart that joint"* to mean *"Pass the [cannabis] joint over to me!"*).

Any explanations as to where it came from?

Comment: It means "don't let it hang in the corner of your mouth in a Humphrey Bogart style", but I'm not sure I can find a authoritative source either.

Comment: [Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bogart): the best resource for all cannabis related language.

Comment: You didn't check [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bogart&searchmode=none)? For shame!

Comment: Apparently this question has just earned me a badge for getting 1000 views. I think that means enough people are interested that it should be reopened.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, how do we vote for reopen?

Comment: @Pacerier: Sadly, [you need 3000 rep to be able to cast a ***reopen*** vote.](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) I tried to vote on your behalf, but apparently I've already done this once so I'm not allowed to do it again. But I *can* see the "reopen" button, and it *doesn't* show a "number of reopen votes so far" value in brackets, so I guess that means 4 others also voted to reopen - and the question *was* reopened, but 5 more people voted to close it again. (In my defence, I was a bit stoned when I originally asked, so my Google-fu was a bit lacking at the time! :)

Comment: Two and a half years after my previous comment, I see this question has now been viewed **25596** times! Even if most of those viewings were from people who already knew the answer (which seems unlikely), at least I don't feel like a complete bozo for having asked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bogart) says:

> 1969, "to keep a joint in your mouth," dangling
>   from the lip like Humphrey Bogart's cigarette in
>   the old movies, instead of passing it on. First
>   attested in "Easy Rider." The word was also used
>   1960s with notions of "get something by
>   intimidation, be a tough guy" (again with reference to the actor and the characters he
>   typically played). In old drinking slang, Captain
>   Cork was "a man slow in passing the bottle."

The Oxford English Dictionary says it is "with allusion to Bogart's frequent on-screen smoking, especially to the long drags he took on cigarettes" and has it from a year earlier:

> Popularized by the 1969 U.S. film *Easy Rider*, the soundtrack of which featured the song cited in quot. 1968.
>
> 1968   ‘Fraternity of Man’ *Don't bogart Me* (transcription of song) in *www.stlyrics.com* (O.E.D. archive) ,   Don't bogart that joint, my friend Pass it over to me.

Here's the [song's lyrics](http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/easyrider/dontbogartme.htm):

> Don't bogart that joint, my friend
>   Pass it over to me.
>   Don't bogart that joint, my friend
>   Pass it over to me.
>   Roll another one
>   Just like the other one.
>   This one's burnt to the end
>   Come on and be a friend.
>   Don't bogart that joint, my friend
>   Pass it over to me.
>   Don't bogart that joint, my friend
>   Pass it over to me.
>   Ro-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-oll another one
>   Just like the other one.
>   You've been hanging on to it
>   And I sure would like a hit.
>   Don't bogart that joint, my friend
>   Pass it over to me.
>   Don't bogart that joint, my friend
>   Pass it over to me

Comment: Just one year earlier, in prisons, it meant something different: [Corrective and Social Psychiatry..., 1967](http://books.google.com/books?id=vAAdAQAAMAAJ&q=%22don't+bogart%22&dq=%22don't+bogart%22&source=bl&ots=ZaparKE9LL&sig=kSQv7M6lTaGG-EMyzyJIEqLTcGM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IlqDUOCnJOq-yQGkuYDACA&ved=0CFwQ6AEwCQ) *There is also a new language."Don't Bogart and don't smack to a supervisor; shine him on or you'll be a stoneout," translated, means: "Don't act either tough or fawning with a supervisor, just act as if you agree with him; if you don't, we won't have a thing to do with you.”*

Comment: @FumbleFingers look at the subject. This is about as clear cut as you're likely to get. :) From a past life more than 30 years ago, this is the interpretation everyone I knew who used it used. Now-a-days I don't know what it means anymore. :)

Comment: Scholarly citation, 1970. Eve Mitchell, "Folklore of Marijuana Smoking", *Southern Folkore Quarterly*, vol 34, p. 127. It's called "Bogarting the joint" when, rather than passing the joint on around the circle, a person hangs onto it and keeps puffing. (p. 128)

Comment: @StoneyB: The coerce/bully/intimidate meaning is included in the Online Etymology Dictionary definition above. It's also the Oxford English Dictionary's first meaning, first quoted in a US university's 1966 slang dictionary.

Comment: 1966&7=swagger, 1968 the song, 1969 the movie, 1970=hog the joint, all contemporary scholarly citations. You don't get better confirmation than that for the ascription.